when i set null on lightning-input type="date" the variable is assigned as null but on date picker it still shows selected value
I have a requirement where i need to check two dates, basically if the Start Date is greater than End Date, i need to clear the current field that is being changed. For the first time it works fine, but whenever i try to click again to trigger the same rule, even if the date variable is null, the date picker is showing the selected value on HTML.
JS
@track creationStartDate = null;
@track creationEndDate = null;

    startChange(event){
        this.checkDatesGreaterToday(event.detail.value);
        this.creationStartDate = event.detail.value;
        let startGreaterThanEnd = this.validateDates();
        this.creationStartDate = startGreaterThanEnd ? null : event.detail.value
    }
    endChange(event){
        this.checkDatesGreaterToday(event.detail.value);
        this.creationEndDate = event.detail.value;
        let startGreaterThanEnd = this.validateDates();
        this.creationEndDate = startGreaterThanEnd ? null : event.detail.value
    }
    validateDates(){
        
        if(this.creationStartDate && this.creationEndDate && (this.creationStartDate>this.creationEndDate)){
            this.showErrorToast('Creation Start Date cannot be greater than Creation End Date', 'error');
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

HTML
<lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto"> 
            <div class="header-column slds-p-right_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="date" label="Creation Start Date" value={creationStartDate} onchange={startChange} max={today}></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto"> 
            <div class="header-column slds-p-right_x-small">       
                <lightning-input type="date" label="Creation End Date" value={creationEndDate} onchange={endChange} max={today}></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>



The date picker component does not automatically refresh its displayed value when the bound variable is set to null. You can force the component to re-render by temporarily setting the value to an empty string before setting it to null.
@track creationStartDate = null;
@track creationEndDate = null;

startChange(event) {
        this.checkDatesGreaterToday(event.detail.value);
        this.creationStartDate = event.detail.value;
        let startGreaterThanEnd = this.validateDates();
        if (startGreaterThanEnd) {
                this.creationStartDate = ''; 
                setTimeout(() => {
                        this.creationStartDate = null;
                }, 0);
        } else {
                this.creationStartDate = event.detail.value;
        }
}

endChange(event) {
        this.checkDatesGreaterToday(event.detail.value);
        this.creationEndDate = event.detail.value;
        let startGreaterThanEnd = this.validateDates();
        if (startGreaterThanEnd) {
                this.creationEndDate = ''; 
                setTimeout(() => {
                        this.creationEndDate = null; 
                }, 0);
        } else {
                this.creationEndDate = event.detail.value;
        }
}

validateDates() {
        if (this.creationStartDate && this.creationEndDate && (this.creationStartDate > this.creationEndDate)) {
                this.showErrorToast('Creation Start Date cannot be greater than Creation End Date', 'error');
                return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
}

When the dates are invalid, the date variables are first set to an empty string and then to null after a short delay using setTimeout. This forces the date picker to refresh and clear the displayed value.

This did the trick, thanks @Tushar Jadav
